# Apache NetBeans 11.1 not working correctly

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-10, netbeans-11

I'm using NetBeans 11.1 on Windows 10.

It has been working properly for the past year as it should but for some reason now I cannot copy/paste text, the 'undo' action isn't working, it cannot automatically highlight any variables that are the same in the class, it just seems that its not working at all.

I've tried restarting it, restarting my PC and reinstalling the program but it hasn't helped at all. Reinstalling it kept my last configuration settings so maybe I should reset all the setting but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often this is caused by a "corrupted" user directory. The location of that directory is shown in the about dialog ("Help -> About") labeled **User Directory**.

The default location in Windows is `%APPDATA%\NetBeans\11.1`

If you want to keep your configuration settings, I would recommend to first export them through the "Export" button in the options dialog ("Tools -> Options").

Then close NetBeans, delete the user directory and restart NetBeans.

To apply your saved configuration use the "Import" button in the options dialog.

I would also recommend to update to 11.2 as that includes several bugfixes and improvements.

Comment: For me deleting the cache in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache did the trick